# Additional information: Method not found: 'Elasticsearch.Net.IApiCallDetails Elasticsearch.Net.IBodyWithApiCallDetails.get_CallDetails()'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

After I upgraded the reference `Elasticsearch.Net` from 1.0.0 to 5.3.0, I keeping getting this error:

`Additional information: Method not found: 'Elasticsearch.Net.IApiCallDetails Elasticsearch.Net.IBodyWithApiCallDetails.get_CallDetails()'.`

I'm not sure where it comes from, I tried to change the code for connection to elasticsearch just like here `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/connecting.html`

It crashes in the controller. When in debug I doesnt actually get to GetServicesStatus(), I guess it only initialize StatsFacade. And the problem is the connection settings etc.

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("servicesState")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetServicesState()
{
    var servicesState = StatsFacade.GetServicesStatus();
    return servicesState;
}



public class StatsFacade : BaseFacade
{
    public const int DefaultDaysRange = 10;

    static SingleNodeConnectionPool connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Stats:ConnectionString"]));

    static ConnectionSettings _apiCallsSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool, new InMemoryConnection())
                                                    .DefaultIndex(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Stats:DefaultIndex"])
                                                    .BasicAuthentication(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Es:User"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Es:Password"])
                                                    .DisableDirectStreaming();

    public static HttpResponseMessage GetServicesStatus()
    {
        ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(_apiCallsSettings);
        //...
        //...
    }
}
```

It crashes on ElasticClient initialization `ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Elasticsearch.NET library was updated but not the NEST library, and this caused the issue.